# Determine the current Rocks version

Tags: linux

How do I find what Rocks version I'm running?

I've tried:

- Looking on the Ganglia page
- `uname -a`
- Google

so far, no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rocks report version
```

Found it 10 seconds after posting. Leave it up for others?